# Selecting just one child using CSS3

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a simple CSS3 question regarding to selecting appropriate child node.

Here is a snippet of current HTML element structure:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><div class="adminNavButton"><p>Pages</p></div></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Make a new page</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Manage pages</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Delete pages</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
and more .... </ul> </nav>
```

In CSS3, I'm trying to select just 
`<a href="#"><div class="adminNavButton"><p>Pages</p></div></a>` using

```
nav ul li a{
}
```

However, it selects every children anchor tags including ones under `<ul><li>`. Do I have to give it a class selector to solve the issue? i.e.

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a class="something" href="#"><div class="adminNavButton"><p>Pages</p></div></a>
```

If you know a technique that works across all browsers, I would appreciate it if you could share it with me.

Thanks in advance,

=================================
Thanks for all your comments guys, :first-child nor :nth-child(1) didn't work from my main project so I've created a new project and tested the method. But it did not work
So here is HTML structure and CSS3.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>asf</title>
    <style>
        ul li a:first-child{
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="">asf</a>
            <div>
                <a href="">asf</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">asfd</a>
            <div>
                <a href="">asf</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">asf</a>
            <div>
                <a href="">asf</a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>


</html>
```

hmm heh =/ (p.s. I've tested it on Firefox and Chrome browser but didn't work)

Comment: You can adress the  first child, something like :`nav ul li a:first`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [first-child](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/%3afirst-child) Pseudo-class:

```
nav > ul > li > a:first-child
{

}
```

Another option that will do what you want is the `>` selector:

```
nav > ul > li > a
{

}
```

The above will only apply to the `Pages` anchor. The `>` is the child selector so the element must be a direct child, unlike when using a space which targets all descendants. If you have siblings of `Pages` then those siblings would also be targeted whereas the first example wouldn't.

**[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3MJY8/)**

From the [W3C docs](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/%3afirst-child):

> The :first-child pseudo-class represents an element that is the first child of some other element. Same as :nth-child(1).

Comment: `:first-child` doesn't actually make a difference here because every `a` is the first child of its `li`. The only thing that matters here is the child selector `>`.

Comment: @BoltClock `first-child` matters if you have siblings of `Pages` and only want to select the first instead of all siblings. As I said in my second example, that will work if you want to target the siblings as well.

Comment: Like I said, it doesn't matter **here** because it's the only sibling that's an `a`.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
nav ul li a:first-child{
}
```

You can also use a class, but if the structure will remain the same (in the first position) the example above is the best route.

Comment: `:first` is not a CSS selector.